# jQuery.ajaxPrefilter: added extra post data parsed as literal [object Object]

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use `$.ajaxPrefilter` to add extra data (object) to every request.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(opt, origOpt, xhr) {
    //app.user is a predefined object, eg. {username:'john', role:1}
    if(app.user) {
        opt.data = $.extend(origOpt.data, app.user);
    }
});
```

But the posted data seems (in Firefox network panel > Params tab) read as literal `[object Object]` instead of key-value pair post data.

Thanks for help.

Comment: did you tried to debug `ajaxPrefilter` callback and see, what `opt.data`, `origOpt.data` and `app.user` looks like at the moment of callback execution?

Comment: @ankhzet: Yes. console.log displays opt.data and origOpt.data to be as expected. But network panel's Params tab displays the data as literal `[object Object]`

Comment: have you tried `opt.data = $.extend({}, origOpt.data, app.user);` or just `$.extend(opt.data, origOpt.data, app.user);` instead?

Comment: The first (`opt.data = $.extend({}, origOpt.data, app.user);` does modifying opt.data, while the other doesn't. I used both command, for no avail.

Comment: Peeped at console. Looks like there is no `data` attribute, parameters are injected directly into `opt`/`origOpt` objects oO, So, maybe `$.extend(opt, app.user);`?

Comment: If in the request (`$.ajax`) we don't define a data property, I think data won't be exist, eg. `$.ajax(url, { success: callback })`. I did like `$.ajax(url, { data: postData, success: callback })`, so I found a data property in both `opt` and `origOpt` params of `ajaxFilter`.

Comment: Updated my answer. Looks like `data` property should be a `string`. No surprise result is arrears as `[object Object]` in debugger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you should try [`.ajaxSetup()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) instead?

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: app.user ? app.user : {}
});
```

**Upd.**

Try to converd `data` to string, as suggested [here](http://www.quora.com/jQuery/Whats-the-proper-way-to-change-data-option-with-ajaxPrefilter):

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, origOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (app.user) {
        options.data = $.param($.extend({}, origOptions.data, app.user));
    }
});
```

Comment: Does it replace or extend the data?

Comment: The code in your update works. I modify it a little to `opt.data = $.param($.extend(origOpt.data, app.user));`, still works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Youre welcome =) P.S. That `({},` part is just to not modify `origOptions.data`, as `$.extend()` modifies it's first parameter

Comment: thanks @ankhzet i was just wondering why jQuery didn't automatically reserialize the parms which is odd. your answer provided the clue.